# Looking for a model in a gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

I have a small world file, say

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://cell</uri>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

that is loaded through a trivial `.load` file. But I'm getting an error:

> Error Code: 11 Msg: Unable to find uri[model://cell]

Simple enough, I thought, I just need to change `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` or set up a symlink. But as soon as I do the process dies when I start it with the same command (`roslaunch my_package my.launch`)

```
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 5661, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode worlds/world.sdf __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/me/.ros/log/0824ba9e-563e-11e9-8942-fcaa1429a868/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/me/.ros/log/0824ba9e-563e-11e9-8942-fcaa1429a868/gazebo-1*.log
```

There is no log file at that location, unfortunately.

Do I need to change other environment variables? Is something else wrong?

Comment: Are you able to manually load this file into gazebo without ROS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gazebo crashes and burns launching empty world in new package](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/gazebo-crashes-and-burns-launching-empty-world-in-new-package)

Comment: Title is misleading. Initially I read it as someone is looking for a model, but looks like it's Gazebo that is failing to locate a model. I'd simply rename the title with the err msg `Error Code: 11 Msg: Unable to find uri[model://cell]`.